# Getting data from the table with two conditions and two different limits

Tags: database, mongodb, api

I have a table of posts where each post has a category field. There are 10 different categories.
I want to write an api that returns 10 posts from the posts table, 7 of them should be from **A** category and 3 of them should be from **B** category.

Is there a way to do this with just one `db.collection("posts").find()`?

The way I do it now is:

```
const postsA = await db.collection("posts").find({ category: "A" }).limit(7).toArray();
const postsB = await db.collection("posts").find({ category: "B" }).limit(3).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could use an aggregation pipeline with 2 `$facet` as follow :

```
const posts = await db.collection("posts").aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "postsA": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "category": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 7
        }
      ],
      "postsB": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "category": "B"
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 3
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
]);
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/